# Dispose on nested Disposable items?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable

I wanted to know if there are any conventions regarding disposal of disposable items nested inside another disposable item(in a property/public field, not as private members). For example, a DataSet contains DataTable(s) and a SqlCommand contains a SqlConnection.

The obvious thing would be for a class to dispose of all Disposable items it owns, and leave the rest. Does there exist such a convention? If it does, how does .NET libraries determine who owns what? How can I find out whether nested objects are being disposed?

PS: I have been wondering about this for a while, and apparently so have others : [What gets disposed when SqlCommand.Dispose is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828788/what-gets-disposed-when-sqlcommand-dispose-is-called)

Edit 1 : Found out that disposing DataSet, does not dispose its tables.

```
// Fill dataset from sqldataadpater.
foreach (DataTable dt in dataSet.Tables)
{
    dt.Disposed += Program.DisposedEventHandler2;
}
Console.WriteLine("Disposing dataset");
dataSet.Dispose(); //Event not fired here.
Console.WriteLine("Disposing datatables maually");
foreach (DataTable dt in dataSet.Tables)
{
    dt.Dispose(); //Event fired here
}
#endregion
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rule of thumb I normally follow is that the class that creates a disposable object, will also dispose it. As an example: a `SqlCommand` does not dispose its connection, because it didn't create it. The `StreamReader` has a strange behavior in this sense, because it will always dispose the underlying stream, even if it is supplied from the outside (I find this very annoying, please vote [HERE](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/577258/add-constructor-overload-to-streamreader-to-prevent-it-to-dispose-the-underlying-stream) when you like Microsoft to fix this).

Comment: While it's annoying sometimes, it means that you can use `new StreamReader(new FileStream(...))` and not have to worry about having two `using` statements... which can often improve readability, IMO.

Comment: @Jon: I understand why the BCL team choose this API design. It guides .NET developers to 'the pit of success' (as Rico Mariani calls it). However, I'm missing the overload with the enum or boolean flag that orders the `StreamReader` to keep the stream alive. In the current design, keeping the stream alive would mean you will have to wrap the stream with a `class DoNotDisposeStreamDecorator : Stream`.

Comment: System.IO.BinaryReader is the most annoying, someone hand you a stream as input parameter to one of your function, you choose this nice reader class to parse the binary data and bang you end disposing the stream...

Answer (score 3):

I would say that *usually* a container will dispose any contained disposable items - `StreamReader` disposes of the underlying stream, for example - but typically I will dispose of each item with a separate `using` statement anyway.

Any concept of "ownership" is really just in documentation and convention. Basically you have to know what will dispose of what, which typically means reading the documentation and hoping it makes it clear. Unfortunately it doesn't always do so :(

Note that there's no single correct answer here - sometimes you may want a type to behave one way, and sometimes the other. Some types explicitly allow you to state whether you're effectively transferring ownership of the resource, although most don't.

Comment: But while using a dataset for example, which I read from using a query, am I expected to dispose of the datatables(and the datatables contain datacolumns and so on...) it contains manually? I really can't think of an elegant way to do that.

Comment: I'm mostly worrying abut the BCL library, since their dispose methods don't have documentation and I use them a lot.

Comment: @apoorv020: `DataTable` and `DataSet` are oddities, to some extent. Unless you're using remoting, you don't need to dispose of them as far as I'm aware. They're really only disposable because they're remotable. They inherit disposability from `MarshalByValueComponent`.

Comment: I added a suggestion to the Microsoft connect site about the `StreamReader` class. Let's all vote: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/577258/add-constructor-overload-to-streamreader-to-prevent-it-to-dispose-the-underlying-stream

Comment: Note that CodeAnalysis (FxCop) will give you warning CA2202 if you dispose both a `StreamReader` and its underlying stream. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is often to supply with the nested IDisposable items an indicator of whether the nested item should be disposed with the container, unless the useful life of the item will never exceed that of the container (in which case disposing the container can dispose the item), or one can be sure that the last entity other than the container to need the contained item will be aware of its existence and need for disposal (meaning the container doesn't have to worry about disposal, since the other item can handle it).

As a simple example, suppose one were designing a UI framework and wanted to provide a control which is supposed to display an `Picture`, and provides a means by which code can supply an image to be displayed.  Assume further that some types of `Picture` have resources that need to be disposed.  There are some situations in which code might want to display a certain `Picture` on multiple controls, which might not all be disposed at the same time.  In such a situation, it would be bad if disposing a control were to dispose its picture.  On the other hand, there are other situations where code might create a picture for the purpose of being displayed, give it to a control, and then not care about it any more.  In such a situation, the code supplying the picture might know that the picture should be disposed when the control no longer needs it, but might not know when that would occur.

Using a parameter to indicate whether a picture should be `Disposed` would allow for clean code in both of the above scenarios.  An alternative approach, which is what Winforms uses, is to have events which occur when either the control's picture changes or when the Image property is changed.  Code which sets the Image property of a control to an image which needs disposal can use those events to take care of it.